# Type of printfn in F#, static vs dynamic string

Tags: f#

I just began toying around with F# in Mono and the following problem arose that I cannot quite understand. Looking up information on `printfn` and `TextWriterFormat` didn't bring enlightenment either, so I thought I'm going to ask here.

In FSI I run the following:

```
> "hello";;
val it : string = "hello"
> printfn "hello";;
hello
val it : unit = ()
```

Just a normal string and printing it. Fine. Now I wanted to declare a variable to contain that same string and print it as well:

```
> let v = "hello" in printfn v ;;
let v = "hello" in printfn v ;;
---------------------------^
\...\stdin(22,28): error FS0001: The type 'string' is not compatible with the type 'Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a>'
```

I understood from my reading that `printfn` requires a constant string. I also understand that I can get around this problem with something like `printfn "%s" v`.

However, I'd like to understand what's going on with the typing here. Clearly, `"hello"` is of type `string` as well as `v` is. Why is there a type problem then? Is `printfn` something special? As I understand it the compiler already performs type-checking on the arguments of the first string, such that `printfn "%s" 1` fails.. this could of course not work with dynamic strings, but I assumed that to be a mere convenience from the compiler-side for the static case.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Good question.  If you look at the type of `printfn`, which is `Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a> -> 'a`, you'll see that the compiler automatically coerces strings into `TextWriterFormat` objects at compile time, inferring the appropriate type parameter `'a`.  If you want to use `printfn` with a dynamic string, you can just perform that conversion yourself:

```
let s = Printf.TextWriterFormat<unit>("hello")
printfn s

let s' = Printf.TextWriterFormat<int -> unit>("Here's an integer: %i")
printfn s' 10

let s'' = Printf.TextWriterFormat<float -> bool -> unit>("Float: %f; Bool: %b")
printfn s'' 1.0 true
```

If the string is statically known (as in the above examples), then you can still have the compiler infer the right generic argument to `TextWriterFormat` rather than calling the constructor:

```
let (s:Printf.TextWriterFormat<_>) = "hello"
let (s':Printf.TextWriterFormat<_>) = "Here's an integer: %i"
let (s'':Printf.TextWriterFormat<_>) = "Float: %f; Bool: %b"
```

If the string is truly dynamic (e.g. it's read from a file), then you'll need to explicitly use the type parameters and call the constructor as I did in the previous examples.

Answer (score 8):

This is only somewhat related to your question, but I think it's a handy trick. In C#, I often have template strings for use with `String.Format` stored as constants, as it makes for cleaner code:

```
String.Format(SomeConstant, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Instead of...

```
String.Format("Some {0} really long {1} and distracting template that uglifies my code {2}...", arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

But since the `printf` family of methods insist on literal strings instead of values, I initially thought that I couldn't use this approach in F# if I wanted to use `printf`. But then I realized that F# has something better - partial function application.

```
let formatFunction = sprintf "Some %s really long %i template %i"
```

That just created a function that takes a string and two integers as input, and returns a string. That is to say, `string -> int -> int -> string`. It's even better than a constant String.Format template, because it's a strongly-typed method that lets me re-use the template without including it inline.

```
let foo = formatFunction "test" 3 5
```

The more I use F#, the more uses I discover for partial function application. Great stuff.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that it is correct to say that the literal value "hello" is of type `String` when used in the context of `printfn "hello"`. In this context the compiler infers the type of the literal value as `Printf.TextWriterFormat<unit>`.

At first it seemed strange to me that a literal string value would have a different inferred type depending on the context of where it was used, but of course we are used to this when dealing with numeric literals, which may represent integers, decimals, floats, etc., depending on where they appear.

If you want to declare the variable in advance of using it via printfn, you can declare it with an explicit type...

```
let v = "hello" : Printf.TextWriterFormat<unit> in printfn v
```

...or you can use the constructor for `Printf.TextWriterFormat` to convert a *normal* String value to the necessary type...

```
let s = "foo" ;;
let v = new Printf.TextWriterFormat<unit>(s) in printfn v ;;
```

Answer (score 4):

As you correctly observe, the printfn function takes a "Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a>" not a string. The compiler knows how to convert between a constant string and a "Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a>", but not between a dynamic string and a "Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a>".

This begs the question why can't it convert between a dynamic string and a "Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a>". This is because the compiler must look at the contents of the string to and determine what control characters are in it ( i.e. %s %i etc), from this is it works out the type of the type parameter of "Printf.TextWriterFormat<'a>" (i.e. the 'a bit). This is a function that is returned by the printfn function and means that the other parameters accepted by printfn are now strongly typed.

To make this a little clear in your example "printfn "%s"" the "%s" is converted into a "Printf.TextWriterFormat unit>", meaning the type of  "printfn "%s"" is string -> unit.