# Why does parseInt(1/0, 19) return 18?

Tags: javascript, parseint

I have an annoying problem in **JavaScript**.

```
> parseInt(1 / 0, 19)
> 18
```

Why does the `parseInt` function return `18`?

Comment: Interesting. But why is this an annoying problem for you? Do you have to handle Infinity in other ways? If so, an `if` might help.

Comment: What the hell were you even doing that required you to work with either base-19 numbers OR division by zero!?

Comment: @ Ray Toal `0 / 0 == NaN`  :)

Comment: When you get confused about JS, just go back to [this quote](http://www.jwz.org/blog/2010/10/every-day-i-learn-something-new-and-stupid/#comment-1021) and remember that the whole damn language was designed and implemented in less than 10 days (according to the person who did it).

Comment: I almost dared to cite here what Zed A Shaw said about JavaScript!! :)

Comment: From the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." This isn't actually an "annoying problem" that you actually face, it's a unrealistic example [that's been floating around the internet forever](http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=2803713&pagenumber=334#post405347339).

Comment: python does the same thing: int('I', 19) == 18

Comment: @oberhamsi Please don't say that. You are talking about something else; `int(1/0, 19)` raises a `ZeroDivisionError`, and `int('Infinity', 19)` raises a `ValueError`. If you consider this to be similar to js....

Comment: @oberhamsi That's hardly the same thing.  This question is a perfect example of why Python's type system is so much more restrictive than JavaScript's - e.g. why you have to explicitly cast other types to strings.

Answer (score 1310, accepted):

The result of `1/0` is [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity).

[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) treats its first argument as a string which means first of all `Infinity.toString()` is called, producing the string `"Infinity"`. So it works the same as if you asked it to convert `"Infinity"` in base 19 to decimal.

Here are the digits in base 19 along with their decimal values:

```
Base 19   Base 10 (decimal)
---------------------------
   0            0
   1            1
   2            2
   3            3
   4            4
   5            5
   6            6
   7            7
   8            8
   9            9
   a            10
   b            11
   c            12
   d            13
   e            14
   f            15
   g            16
   h            17
   i            18
```

What happens next is that `parseInt` scans the input `"Infinity"` to find which part of it can be parsed and stops after accepting the first `I` (because `n` is not a valid digit in base 19).

Therefore it behaves as if you called `parseInt("I", 19)`, which converts to decimal 18 by the table above.

Comment: then why parseInt(1/0, 24) gives me 151176378  ?

Comment: @mithunsatheesh Try `parseInt('Infini',24)`.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: Because in base 24 `n` is also a valid digit, so it actually ends up doing `parseInt("Infini", 24)`.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: probably because during parsing with base of 19 only the first character is parsed (n is not within list of chars for this base)? In case of base 24 there are more characters that can be parsed, so the result is bigger.

Comment: @Tadeck: Yes because we love JavaScript, have eyes on it to always learn something new :) +1

Comment: Why someone wants to 'program' in a language which behaves like this is beyond me.

Comment: @FransBouma: JS is beautiful in its own way. And really, no part of what happens here is unreasonable in a dynamic language.

Comment: @Jon: this artifact isn't the result of dynamic language; it's a result of loose-typing. In strictly-typed dynamic language, the implicit conversion of Infinity (float) to "Infinity" (string) would not happen, to prevent this sort of silliness.

Comment: @LieRyan It is not implicit. `parseInt` explicitly converts the argument to be parsed to string by calling `ToString` on it. What is the correct string presentation of `Infinity`? `"Infinity"` seems reasonable to me. But there is no implicit conversion anywhere.

Comment: `parseInt` is meant to parse a string, not an arbitrary object on which `toString` is called. The ability to pass in `Infinity` (NOT a string) and have it converted to `"Infinity"` is in fact an non-obvious, implicit conversion.

Comment: Can't say I would agree with this. [Implicit type conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion) has to do with automated conversion not undocumented feature. Automatic conversion of `int` to `long` in C is very well documented, still implicit though.

Comment: @Jon: This is non-obvious & surprising behavior which has nothing to do with JS being a "dynamic language". It requires knowing that the IEEE floating point standard arbitrarily defines 1/0 as positive infinity instead of being (the more widely accepted, obvious and unsurprising) undefined value. I believe JS is a great language but calling this reasonable behavior smacks of Stockholm Syndrome.

Comment: As a physicist (or mathematician) I'd assume `x/0` to return `undefined`, not `Infinity` - just like mattdeboard says.

Comment: @MuhammadAlkarouri this conversion is not like `int` to `long` or what is described in that part of the article at all, it's closer to calling [`itoa`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/), except of course it's not integer to string but double (which can be `Infinity`) to string

Comment: @mattdeboard: I agree that it is surprising, but disagree that it's unreasonable. Every decision has pros and cons; for me, agreement with IEE 754 is a property more desirable than agreement with an informed non-programmer's expectation. Developers have been trained to accept the models of computer systems as "correct" even when they differ from more widely accepted models because they offer specific engineering benefits. I don't expect *everyone* to agree with this POV, but I also don't think it's fair to call it Stockholm Syndrome.

Comment: @Esailija: my point was that _implicit_ does not mean _undocumented_. Conversion of `int` to `long`, or `int` to `string`, or converting a [`string` to a `TextWriterFormat<'T>` in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2162081/336455) are all implicit as long as the automatic calling of [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) or another suitable conversion function is handled automatically and not called explicitly by the programmer.

Comment: I think this is a combination of two problems: 1) Implicitly calling toString(), 2) The base being an optional parameter

Comment: Very interesting topic indeed, with amazing explanations! :-) And `2*parseInt(1/0,19)+6` gives you the [ultimate answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) ... ;-)

Comment: Talk about obscure coding. One could win "IOJSCC" with such things :))

Comment: @munchybunch - You stated yourself that "`parseInt` is meant to parse a string", as indeed the "parse" part of its name implies (and as all reputable JS references state), so if somebody deliberately passes an argument that is _not_ a string they really shouldn't be too surprised if they don't get whatever result they expected.

Comment: Isn't part of the "stupidity" that `parseInt` is willing to parse an argument where only a prefix is a valid number in the given base? Rather than report an error and/or return `undefined` when the input has garbage after the numeric prefix, it simply ignores it. Unfortunately, this is quite common; PHP does the same thing, as does C's `atoi()` and similar functions.

Answer (score 230):

Here's the sequence of events:

- `1/0` evaluates to `Infinity`
- `parseInt` reads `Infinity` and happily notes that `I` is 18 in base 19
- `parseInt` ignores the remainder of the string, since it can't be converted.

Note that you'd get a result for any base `>= 19`, but not for bases below that. For bases `>= 24`, you'll get a larger result, as `n` becomes a valid digit at that point.

Comment: @Thilo BTW, what would be the reason, why it *might* stop at 19, if base's greater? Do you know, what's the greatest base JS can iterpret?

Comment: @Nordvind The largest base `parseInt` will accept is 36, since there are 26 letters in the English alphabet, and the convention is to use digits then letters as the set of valid digits in the given base.

Comment: On bullet point #2, may I suggest changing `Infinity` to `"Infinity"`...

Comment: @CJBS Correct, but there’s a bullet point missing before that: `parseInt` expects a string as its first argument, so `Infinity` is coerced to `"Infinity"`; also that should be an ordered list, not an unordered one. But the accepted answer already explains everything…

Answer (score 39):

To add to the above answers:

parseInt is intended to parse strings into numbers (the clue is in the name).  In your situation, you don't want to do any parsing at all since 1/0 is *already* a number, so it's a strange choice of function.  If you have a number (which you do) and want to convert it to a particular base, you should use [toString with a radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) instead.

```
var num = 1 / 0;
var numInBase19 = num.toString(19); // returns the string "Infinity"
```

Answer (score 14):

To add to the above answers

`parseInt(1/0,19)` is equivalent to `parseInt("Infinity",19)`

Within base 19 numbers `0-9` and  `A-I` `(or a-i)` are a valid numbers. So, from the "Infinity" it takes `I` of base 19 and converts to base 10 which becomes 18
Then it tries to take the next character i.e. `n` which is not present in base 19 so discards next characters (as per javascript's behavior of converting string to number)

So, if you write `parseInt("Infinity",19)` OR  `parseInt("I",19)` OR `parseInt("i",19)` the result will be same i.e `18`.

Now, if you write `parseInt("I0",19)` the result will be `342`
as `I X 19 (the base)^1 + 0 X 19^0`  = `18 X 19^1 + 0 X 19^0` = `18 X 19 + 0 X 1`  = `342`

Similarly, `parseInt("I11",19)` will result in `6518`

i.e.

```
  18 X 19^2  +   1 X 19^1   +  1 X 19^0
= 18 X 19^2  +   1 X 19^1   +  1 X 19^0
= 18 X 361   +   1 X 19     +  1 X 1
= 6498  +  19  +  1
= 6518
```