# parseInt() in Javascript giving weird results

Tags: javascript, parseint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: why does parseInt(1/0, 19) return 18?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340673/javascript-why-does-parseint1-0-19-return-18)

Why does parseInt(1/0, 19) evaluate to 18 in Javascript ? I understand 19 in not a permissible radix but still can someone tell how things are working here ?

Comment: Why are you dividing by zero?

Comment: +1, this is fascinating: `parseInt(1/0, 15) --> NaN
parseInt(1/0, 19) --> 18
parseInt(1/0, 20) --> 18
parseInt(1/0, 25) --> 185011843
parseInt(1/0, 28) --> 324267766`

Comment: Let's say I am passing an expression to parseInt taken from user & he may type whatever he feels like. It hurts to cover corner cases but still someone has to.

Comment: 19 *is* a permissible radix... a more pertinent question is, why are you converting to base-19?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right place. :)

Comment: Also, this is an exact duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, quick javascript consoling led to the answer:

```
> 1/0
Infinity
> parseInt("Infinity", 19)
18
```

`parseInt` seems to convert the first argument to a string, e.g.:

```
> parseInt(11, 2)
3
```

so, it's converting the string "Infinity", which explains everything.