# parseInt method in javascript is returning a junk value

Tags: javascript, parseint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does parseInt(1/0, 19) return 18?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340673/why-does-parseint1-0-19-return-18)

I was parsing an integer from the result of an expression in javascript.
The expression was `(a/b,24)`, and it is in a method, so I do not have a check on division by zero.
and I am parsing the integer as `parseInt(a/b,24)`

But I found an unusual thing in it `when a=1, b=0 the result was 151176378.`

Please explain the reason for this discrepancies.

Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Isn't `a=1, b=0 - a/b` going to cause "divide by 0" problems?

Comment: It should give an error, but it is returning that value, any idea, how?

Comment: Here's your answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340673/why-does-parseint1-0-19-return-18

Comment: Why on earth are people allowing div by zero errors and then parsing to a weird base and wondering about strange results???

Comment: @Christoph: This line is written in my method in which a, b comes as a parameter.

Comment: Sure, but does that hinder you to do a check `(b)?parseInt(..):"error"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `parseInt(a/b, 24)` you are attempting to parse the result of `a/b` in base 24 (no idea what this number system would look like).

`a/b` returns `Infinity` which is converted to the string value `"Infinity"` and then parsed using base 24 so you would get the same result with `parseInt("Infinity", 24)`. You would get a result of `NaN` with any base of 18 or less (i.e. `parseInt(1/0, 18)`).

Comment: You can't use backslash `\\` as operator for division. This leads to syntax error!

Comment: @core1024, must remember to proof read.