# How to convert a string of comma separated numbers to integers?

Tags: javascript, string, string-conversion

I have an array of values such that `arr = [108, 109]`. I then converted them to a string using `arr.toString()`, thus getting `"108, 109"`. The reason I did this was because my API required that this parameter arr asked for an array to string conversion. How can I turn this value into an integer?

I tried doing `const test = parseInt(arr)` but I only get `108`. Why is that? I essentially just want the values `108, 109`.

Comment: This is about why - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340673/why-does-parseint1-0-19-return-18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split the values with comma using the `split()` method like this.

```
arr.split(',')
```

After that you will get each value separated in an array which will be accessible by giving array index. So `arr[0]` will include 108 and `arr[1]` will include 109. Now all that's left to do is parse them individually.

```
parseInt(arr[0]) 
parseInt(arr[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting `108` is due to [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) stopping after any invalid outcome. So what you are basically trying to to is:

```
parseInt('108, 109');
```

which stops at the comma.

In case you need the whole array I suggest using [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) together with [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const test = '108, 109'.split(',').map(Number);
console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

the values 108 and 109 are different, so you have to `parseInt` them separately by doing `parseInt("108")` and  `parseInt("109")`