# Template strings in F#?

Tags: f#

I'm new to F#, and want to know if there is anything in F# similar to [template strings in Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings). So I can simply do something like:

```
    >>> d = dict(who='tim', what='car')
    >>> Template('$who likes $what').substitute(d)
    'tim likes car'
```

Comment: `printf` and friends are reasonably close

Comment: It could be done as a type provider, with the benefit of having all holes statically checked. I'm writing a similar one but specialized for XML https://github.com/mausch/XmlLiteralsTypeProvider/blob/master/Tests/Program.fs

Comment: What I described in my previous comment has now been implemented! http://blog.mavnn.co.uk/type-safe-printf-via-type-providers/

Answer (score 9):

The idiomatic way of doing that in F# is with `sprintf`:

```
let newString = sprintf "First Name: %s Last Name: %s" "John" "Doe"
```

Additionally, you have access to the .net `String.Format`:

```
let newString = String.Format("First Name: {0} Last Name: {1}", "John", "Doe")
```

The benefit of the first one is that it is type-safe (i.e. you can't pass a string to an integer formatter like "%d").  As noted by Benjol in the comments, it's not possible to pass a format string to `sprintf` because it is statically typed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162081/type-of-printfn-in-f-static-vs-dynamic-string?rq=1) for more information on that.

Comment: And the benefit of the second one is that you *can* pass it a string variable as format string :)

Answer (score 7):

New in F# 5 is [string interpolation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/f-5-update-for-august/#string-interpolation):

```ml
let firstName = "John" 
let lastName = "Doe" 

let newString = $"First Name: {firstName} Last Name: {lastName}"
```

Or without local bindings (note the triple quotes):

```ml
let newString = $"""First Name: {"John"} Last Name: {"Doe"}"""
```

Older versions of F# should use `sprintf`:

```ml
let newString = sprintf "First Name: %s Last Name: %s" "John" "Doe"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of anything built-in to the core libs that would work in the key-value fashion that you're looking for, but you can have type-checked formatted strings with the **[sprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370455.aspx)** function:

```
let intro = sprintf "I am %d years old. My name is %s" 35 "Sam"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dynamic list of substitutions, you can achieve what Template() does with a simple fold:

```
let substitutions = [("who", "tim"); ("what", "car")]
let template = "{who} likes {what}"
let replace (str : string) (key, value) = str.Replace(sprintf "{%s}" key, value)  

List.fold replace template substitutions
```